# Hyperledger peers with TLS in kubernetes cluster constantly keep throwing TLS handshake errors

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Below are the peer logs:

```
2019-12-06 07:00:31.121 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO fa975 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.131.215:25731
2019-12-06 07:00:31.215 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO fa976 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.131.215:20784
2019-12-06 07:00:31.301 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO fa977 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=192.168.131.215:8059
2019-12-06 07:00:31.512 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO fa978 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=ChaincodeServer remoteaddress=192.168.163.185:46359
2019-12-06 07:00:31.768 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO fa979 TLS handshake failed with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=192.168.131.215:34603
```

Everything is working fine. We are able to do transactions on the chaincode. 
Can anyone please help us on this issue?

EDITED: 9th Dec. 2019

Below is the peer deployment yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: korg60
  name: peer1-korg60
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app: hyperledger
       role: peer
       org: korg60
       name: peer1-korg60
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: hyperledger
       role: peer
       org: korg60
       name: peer1-korg60
    spec:
     containers:
       - name: couchdb
         image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest
         ports:
          - containerPort: 5984
       - name: peer1-korg60
         image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4
         env:
          - name: FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME
            value: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
          - name: FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES
            value: /data/korg60-ca-chain.pem
          - name: ENROLLMENT_URL
            value: http://peer1:peer1pw@ica-korg60.korg60:7054
          - name: PEER_NAME
            value: peer1-korg60
          - name: PEER_HOME
            value: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
          - name: PEER_HOST
            value: some.domain.com:7051
          - name: PEER_NAME_PASS
            value: peer1:peer1pw
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_ID
            value: peer1-korg60
          - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
            value: some.domain.com:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
            value: korg60MSP
          - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
            value: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/msp
          - name: CORE_VM_ENDPOINT
            value: unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
          - name: CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT
            value: "true"
          - name: FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC
            value: "peer=INFO"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
            value: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/tls/server.crt
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
            value: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/tls/server.key
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
            value: /data/korg60-ca-chain.pem
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES
            value: /data/korg60-ca-chain.pem
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE
            value: /data/tls/peer1-korg60-client.crt
          - name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE
            value: /data/tls/peer1-korg60-client.key
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
            value: "false"
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT
            value: some.domain.com:7051
          - name: CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE
            value: "true"
          - name: CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS
            value: 0.0.0.0:7052
          - name: CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE
            value: CouchDB
          - name: CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS
            value: localhost:5984
          - name: ORG
            value: korg60
          - name: ORG_ADMIN_CERT
            value: /data/orgs/korg60/msp/admincerts/cert.pem
          - name: GODEBUG
            value: "netdns=go"
         ports:
          - containerPort: 7051
          - containerPort: 7052
          - containerPort: 7053
         command: ["sh"]
         args:  ["-c", "/scripts/start-peer.sh 2>&1"]
         volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /scripts
            name: rca-scripts
          - mountPath: /data
            name: rca-data
          - mountPath: /host/var/run/
            name: run
     volumes:
       - name: rca-scripts
         persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: rca-scripts-korg60-pvc
       - name: rca-data
         persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: rca-data-korg60-pvc
       - name: run
         hostPath:
           path: /run

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: korg60
  name: peer1-korg60
spec:
 selector:
   app: hyperledger
   role: peer
   org: korg60
   name: peer1-korg60
 type: NodePort
 ports:
   - name: endpoint
     protocol: TCP
     port: 7051
     targetPort: 7051
     nodePort: 30401
   - name: endpoint-chaincode
     protocol: TCP
     port: 7052
     targetPort: 7052
     nodePort: 30402
```

Below is the ordere yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: koinearth
  name: orderer1-koinearth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app: hyperledger
       role: orderer
       org: koinearth
       name: orderer1-koinearth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: hyperledger
       role: orderer
       org: koinearth
       name: orderer1-koinearth
    spec:
     containers:
       - name: orderer1-koinearth
         image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4
         env:
          - name: FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME
            value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer
          - name: FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES
            value: /data/koinearth-ca-chain.pem
          - name: FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC
            value: "peer=INFO"
          - name: ENROLLMENT_URL
            value: http://orderer1:orderer1pw@ica-koinearth.koinearth:7054
          - name: ORDERER_HOME
            value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer
          - name: ORDERER_HOST
            value: orderer1-koinearth.koinearth
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS
            value: 0.0.0.0
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD
            value: file
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE
            value: /data/genesis.block
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID
            value: koinearthMSP
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR
            value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer/msp
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED
            value: "true"
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED
            value: "false"
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY
            value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE
            value: /etc/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL
            value: debug
          - name: ORDERER_DEBUG_BROADCASTTRACEDIR
            value: data/logs
          - name: ORG
            value: koinearth
          - name: ORG_ADMIN_CERT
            value: /data/orgs/koinearth/msp/admincerts/cert.pem
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS
            value: '[/data/koinearth-ca-chain.pem]'
          - name: ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS
            value: '[/data/koinearth-ca-chain.pem]'
          - name: ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE
            value: "true"
          - name: ORDERER_KAFKA_VERSION
            value: 1.0.0
          - name: GODEBUG
            value: "netdns=go"
         ports:
          - containerPort: 7050
         command: ["sh"]
         args:  ["-c", "/scripts/start-orderer.sh 2>&1"]
         volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca
            name: orderer
          - mountPath: /scripts
            name: rca-scripts
          - mountPath: /data
            name: rca-data
     volumes:
       - name: orderer
         persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: orderer-koinearth-pvc
       - name: rca-scripts
         persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: rca-scripts-koinearth-pvc
       - name: rca-data
         persistentVolumeClaim:
             claimName: rca-data-koinearth-pvc

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: koinearth
  name: orderer1-koinearth
spec:
 selector:
   app: hyperledger
   role: orderer
   org: koinearth
   name: orderer1-koinearth
 type: NodePort
 ports:
   - name: endpoint
     protocol: TCP
     port: 7050
     targetPort: 7050
     nodePort: 30300
```

Peer and orderer identity is created in the startup scripts and stored locally in the container.

Comment: This does not seem to be k8s issue. Verify identities as TLS certs.

Comment: Provide us complete details of a peer, orderer deployment manifests and how you generate artifacts just looking TLS error cannot able to identify because TLS errors are more generic

Comment: @NarendranathReddy I have updated the question with the information you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are using wrong certificates.

What are the two parties?
2 peers or 1 peer 1 orderer?
Or maybe the client?

The two parties must have valid TLS certificates, here you are using some wrong ones.

Comment: this setup has 2orgs each has 2 peers, 3 orderers(one with TLS). The client is our node.js application. But I don't think so this issue with client as our application is able to do all the transactions.

Comment: is this happening when you call getNetwork() ?
I am facing issues too with NodeSDK and it seems to have some issues related to TLS. check it here: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1234
I am migrating to Java SDK now due to this.

Comment: no, It is not happening while calling through nodeJS client. Peers are continuous logging this error. The same is not happening with the docker setup. There is some connection with Kubernetes.